# How to make output horizontally that has different lines without using /n

Tags: c, loops

I am trying to make a loop of:

```
hi
:)
```

for number of times that the user inputs **horizontally**.
So for example, my goal is:

```
num =3

hi hi hi
:) :) :)
```

For now, my codes are

```
  for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        {
          printf("\n hi \n:) \n" );
        }
  return 0;
```

Since I wanted a line difference between `hi` and `:)`, I used `\n`.
However, due to this my output is shown vertically, not horizontally:

```
num=3    
hi
:)
hi
:)
hi
:)
```

How can I make my output horizontally when I have line spacing in the output?

Comment: Hint: Try printing all the `hi` in one for loop and all the `:)` in a second for loop

Comment: Print `hi␠` three times, then print a newline, then print `:)␠` three times, then print a newline. This suggests two loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. As already mentioned in the comments, two loops would suffice.

```c
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   printf("hi ");
}

printf("\n")

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
   printf(":) ");
}
```

Comment: if I try that, I get my output as
hi
hi
:)
:)

Comment: spaces in between hi - hi - :) - :)

Comment: I'll check my indentation

Comment: I added `{` and `}` braces for each loop, now indentation would not matter. Try it.